(Random) Matrix Perturbations with all eigenvalues close to the real line
This is a bit of an open question. I have a specific application in mind, but for now I`m mostly interested in whether someone could point out any results in this direction.
So, for various classes of matrices $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times x}$ we know what their eigenvalues look like. Triangular matrices have all eigenvalues real etc.
In random matrix theory we often deal with matrices where individual entries are i.i.d and drawn from some general distribution with fairly general constraints (0 mean, 1\N variance, bounded fourth moment etc.). For several such matrices, like the GUE, GOE, and so on, we can provide measure such that the as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the empirical law of such matrices converges weakly to that measure. So in the asymptotic limit we can describe the eigenvalues using that measure.
Most of the time, we can also say how the eigenvalue spectra will behave under perturbations that are small compared to the original matrix (operator or Frobenius norm). As I understand, this is fleshed out in terms of what is called the pseudo-spectrum. So the pseduo-spectrum of $A$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A+\epsilon$, where epsilon is some matrix with small norm (is this correct?).
Now what I'm interested in is this: for some given general matrix $A$ that we perturb with a random matrix $\epsilon$. Usually, if the matrix didn't already have complex eigenvalues, this perturbation will definitely introduce some eigenvalues that are complex. Now can we say anything about the matrices $\epsilon'$ such that for $\lambda_i \in Eig(A+\epsilon), Im(\lambda_i) \leq \delta$, where $\delta$ is some arbitrary but very small constant.
Is this an active field of research? Is there any literature on this? I'd be greateful if someone could point out some sources.
To offer a concrete example: If A is lower-triangular and $\epsilon$ is upper triangular, are all eigenvalues close to real?

symmetric are positive definite? what about $-I$?

Sorry, I wanted to say symmetric positive definite matrices have all eigenvalues real and positive, which I guess is just the definition. Ill delete that. Thank you.

If you start with a matrix $A$ with distinct real eigenvalues, then for small perturbation the matrix $A+\epsilon$ still has only real distinct eigenvalues

For example, if you start from a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $x<y$, you need a perturbation with norm at least $(y-x)/2$, otherwise all the eigenvalues are still real

@Exodd: can we bound the size of the imaginary part using the norm of the perturbation?

By the Bauer-Fike theorem, they are bounded by the norm of the perturbation times the condition number of the diagonalizing base change of $A$ (when A is diagonalizable)

That only applies when $\epsilon = \delta A$. However, I'm interested in the case when $\epsilon$ is not constrained in this way.

What I'm looking for is something more along the lines of Weyl's inequality. But that only holds for Hermitian matrices.
